# Empty page when uploading using Google App engine Photofeed sample

Tags: google-app-engine, image-uploading, google-cloud-storage

I've deployed the `Photofeed` example project provided by Google to the app engine.
I've configured the `appengine-web.xml` and the main page loads.
After I select an image and click the 'upload' button, I'm transffered to another URL, something like `http://mydomain.appstop.com/_ah/upload/LONG_STRING/`, I believe this should be the upload URL received from the server but I'm not sure.
The page is empty (empty source) and when I check the bucket through the online browser, I can see nothing was uploaded.
Anyway I'm not quite sure about the error or what went wrong. (Is there somewhere I can see logs of the app ?)
I've set the `entityManagerFactory` in `appengine-web.xml` to `"com.google.cloud.demo.model.nosql.DemoEntityManagerNoSqlFactory"`.
Also i've set the application `ID`, `version` and `bucket name`